# SQL syntax UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update DATA value in column "InstalDate" with current date for ID < 450 and update with DATE='2017-05-05'  for the rest of table records and it need to be done in one command, so how to do it in one command?

I managed to do it but only for ID < 450 and don't know how to add second condition in one command.

UPDATE tabela SET InstalDate= NOW() WHERE ID<450;

Answer (score 1):

could using a case in values to assign

```
UPDATE tabela 
SET InstalDate = case when ID <450 then  NOW() else '2017-05-05' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding conditions in UPDATE query is really simple you can simply use

```
UPDATE tabela SET InstalDate= NOW() WHERE ID<450 AND username='admin';
```

`username='admin'` is an example with an `AND` operator you change column name and its value

Answer (score 0):

```
IF ID<450
    UPDATE tabela SET InstalDate= NOW()
ELSE
    UPDATE tabela SET InstalDate= '2017-05-05'
```

can you try this